# Why is my assertion failing when reading a NamedTemporaryFile?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, nose, temporary-files

I'm writing code that reads a file and creates a dictionary based on the contents of that file. The code is quite straightforward, but I'd like to test the edge cases.

Here's my attempt:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from nose.tools import *

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        my_dict = { dict(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f }
    return my_dict

def test_read_file():
    file_contents = b"""Hello,World"""
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as fp:
        fp.write(file_contents)
        my_dict = read_file(fp.name)
    print(my_dict)
    assert my_dict == { "Hello" : "World" }
```

Unfortunately this assertion fails because `my_dict` is an empty dictionary.

My understanding is that once a `NamedTemporaryFile` is closed, it is destroyed, so I don't expect it to be destroyed until **directly** after `read_file`'s `my_dict` is populated. `fp` is being opened twice: once to write and once to read -- is this the troublemaker?

Is this the right way to test a function that reads a file? If so, why is my assertion failing? If not, what's a better mechanism for writing this test?

Comment: You might need to call `fp.flush()` to ensure the data is actually written to the file before you try to read it.

Comment: @chepner Ugh, that was it. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it. It's almost certainly a dupe, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the write to ensure the data is written before reading.

```
def test_read_file():
    file_contents = b"""Hello,World"""
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as fp:
        fp.write(file_contents)
        fp.flush()
        my_dict = read_file(fp.name)
    print(my_dict)
    assert my_dict == { "Hello" : "World" }
```

Comment: Accepting this because it answers the question of _why_, but upvoted the other answer because it's a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a real file, you can use an in-memory file-like object. This requires either mocking `open`, or changing your API to take a file-like object instead of a file name.

```
import unittest.mock
import io

def test_read_file():
    file_contents = io.BytesIO(b"""Hello,World""")
    m = unittest.mock.mock_open(read_data=file_contents)
    with unittest.mock.patch('__main__.open', m):
        my_dict = read_file("fake.txt")
    print(my_dict)
    assert my_dict == { "Hello" : "World" }
```

Comment: `unittest` contains some pretty crazy stuff! I like the idea of an in-memory object, though.